# как обрезать блок под карты

Tags: css, yandex-maps-api

поступил такой заказ сделать карту на основе `yandex map api` по макету -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

карту импортировал подключил , теперь как обрезать её ?

вырезать часть карты как показано в `yandex песочнице` не подойдёт так как - во первых мне нужно получить москву в зуме как показано на макете , а во вторых при зуме карта не сохраняет обрезаность.

я думаю над тем что бы блоку к которому загружается карта сделать фиксированую ширину + высоту и добавить `overflow:hidden` , а сам блок обрезать по точкам в форме как показано на макете.

можете подсказать как это сделать ?

или у вас есть другое решения для реализации ?

Comment: А нельзя сделать карту в svg, разбить на участки?

Comment: @Arcadiy, +1 согласен :)

Comment: карта должна быть активной (перемещения , зум , при нажатии ставить точки , и также при нажатии на объекты они должны забиватся в навигационую панель) тому я не думаю что карта в svg справится с этим )

Comment: я вот ещё думаю над вариантом наложить маску которая будет прозрачная но за границами будет скрывать всё

Comment: @GetWorld каким образом форма маски будет у вас меняться при перемещении по карте и при зуме?

Comment: @GetWorld ещё как вариант сделать png с альфоой в центре, абсолютом вывести и форме тоже абсолют,  управлять Z-indexАми

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял сценарий, то контур Москвы планируется сделать статичным, а карту внутрь через API Яндекс пробросить с актуальными данными.

Сразу замечу, что такой вариант Яндекс забракует не глядя и в лучшем случае просто заблочат. Ведь вы своим контуром однозначно закроете копирайты, а это недопустимо даже на коммерческих тарифах.

Потому решение - не терять время, найти подходящую карту и сделать статичную картинку с контуром и нужной инфой внутри (опять же не на подложке Яндекса при текущем ТЗ).